# How To Fix Laravel Decimal Number Problem

Tags: laravel

My Product Price------$250.
Discount-------------- 27%.
Total----------------$182.5

Now I want the Product Price to show $183. I don't want to show the decimal numbers.

My Code

```
<tr>
       <td>Total:</td>
       <td>${{ $data->price - (($data->price * $data->discount_percent) / 100 ) }}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ceil(182.5) PHP function for that

Example

```
<tr>
   <td>Total:</td>
   <td>${{ $data->price - (ceil($data->price * $data->discount_percent) /100 
    ) }}
</td></tr>
```